# Import library into Jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, groovy-grape

In my Jenkins build, I have a Groovy script(because I am using the Pipeline plugin) where I am trying to make an API call using `OkHttpClient`.

I have the following Grape code that I got from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.7.5):

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.squareup.okhttp', module='okhttp', version='2.7.5')
)
```

For this, I am getting:

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.squareup.okkhttp#okhttp;2.7.5: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.squareup.okhttp#okhttp;2.7.5: not found]
at sun.reflect.NativeContructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Can't Grape retrieve packages when running in a Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: what is a jenkins version?

Comment: The version is `2.46`

Comment: Is the [Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) installed. They support `@Grab` since version 2.3

Comment: I installed this plugin and restarted Jenkins, but I get the same error.

Comment: how is it defined? is it in pipeline or in regular job? Is it "Groovy script" or "System groovy script" step?"

Comment: It's in a pipeline. I have a `Jenkinsfile` file in my project, and in Jenkins I have the configuration `Pipeline script from Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: I think it is related to sandbox. did you try to use it as a script with sandbox disabled?

Comment: No, I haven't. Can I disable the Sandbox on a pipeline?

Comment: not yet. the [ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28178) is still open

Comment: Btw, there was an issue with grabbing from default repo, try specufying maven central expliciltly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running a Jenkins Groovy console script that used the @Grab annotation. The error was caused by the Jenkins Groovy not being able to resolve my corporate proxyhost server.

The Groovy proxyserver can be set on the command line, like this:

`groovy -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourproxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=portNumber yourscript.groovy`

but I was not able to find out how to do that for the Jenkins Groovy.

I ended with the following workaround:

You can install the required library  from the command line (assuming you have access to the Jenkins server). In that case the proxyserver is easily specified as follows:

```
grape -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.server.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=port install %groupId% %artifactId% [%version%]
```

Also insure that you install the library while logged in under the Jenkins user account. Grapes libraries are user account specific.